# References on Computational Complexity and Statistics

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, references, algorithms

I'm reading Elements of Statistical Computing: Numerical Computation. And this book is the only one I've found that deals with computational complexity in the context of statistical inference. Does anyone know any other references? (books, articles, blogs, etc.)

Comment: A thesis titled [The Computational Complexity of Machine Learning](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~mkearns/papers/thesis.pdf) might be relevant.